# Extract time from factor column in R

Tags: r

I would like to extract the time from a table column sd_data$start in R with the following characteristics:

```
str(sd_data$start)
Factor w/ 122 levels "01/03/2017 08:00",..: 1 2 5 10 12 14 18 19 20 21 ...
```

I found similar questions on the forum but so far all the answers have only given me NAs or blank values (00:00:00) so I see no other option than raise the question again specifically for my dataset.

I have managed to extract the dates and move them to a new column in the table with little effort and I am very surprised how difficult it is (for me at least) to do the same for hours, minutes and seconds. I must be overlooking something.

```
sd_data$start_date <- as.Date(sd_data$start,format='%d/%m/%Y')
sd_data$start_time <-
```

Thanks in advance for helping me to find the right lines of code to complete this task.

Here an example of what I am trying to do and where I am failing to get the time out.

```
smpldata <- "01/03/2017 08:00"
smpltime <-as.Date(as.character(smpldata),format='%d/%m/%Y %M:%S')
smpltime
# [1] 08:00 = what I would like to see
# [1] "2017-03-01" = what I am seeing
```

Comment: Convert the whole string to datetime, i.e. `as.Date(sd_data$start,format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')` and then use format to get hours, minutes , days etc...

Comment: I know it's late, bu I edited the answer to include exactly what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using `as.character()` to convert to character before convert to date, because the factor type is not well transformed. And including the other string elements on the date format as suggested above by Sotos.

```
sd_data$start_date <-
  as.Date(as.character(sd_data$start),
          format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Another tip is to take a look at lubridate package. It's very usefull for this kind of task.

```
library(lubridate)

smpldata <- as.factor("01/03/2017 08:00")
(smpltime <-dmy_hm(as.character(smpldata)))

[1] "2017-03-01 08:00:00 UTC"
```

Here you still see the date. You can handle just the time for plots and other needs using `hour()` and `minute()`.

```
hour(smpltime)
[1] 8

minute(smpltime)
[1] 0
```

Or you can use the `format()` function to get exactly what you want.

```
format(smpltime, "%H:%M:%S")
[1] "08:00:00"

format(smpltime, "%H:%M")
[1] "08:00"
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno,  I have added a reproducible example to my original question. I have also tried using the 'as.character' function but was unsuccessful getting the time out of the data.

Comment: I added an example with lubridate, Peter. After that you can handle just time.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, This is getting close but unfortunately lubridate leaves me with two characters (8) and (0) where I would like to have the time extracted to actual hours and minutes (08:00) so it is recognized by R as being a time. This so I can plot my table with data against the time on the a-axis in a graph. It is a task I could also do in Excel before loading the data into R but that would beat the purpose of choosing to work with R. Perhaps the answer is that R can not recognize time separate from the date. In that case I just need to find a way for R to hide the date and only show the time

Comment: ...reading through the date and time tutorials for R again I realize now that what I had in mind is not possible. R does simply not allow 'a time' to be separated from 'a date and time' value unless it is extracted as a character or integer. This means I will need to use an alternative approach and use the date and time together to display the values by hour. http://r4ds.had.co.nz/dates-and-times.html